# WAS6.1 to liberty migration

Tags: server, migration, websphere, ibm-rad

We are currently migrating our application, that is running with RAD 8.0 and WAS 6.1, to RAD 9.5 and Liberty profile 8.5.5.5. The server configuration setup for liberty profile is done.

While running the application, we are facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, since the com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar is missing in Liberty server. This is one of the runtime jars of WAS 6.1.

kindly let us know whether this jar is available with Liberty server. Also provide some inputs on how to include this runtime jar and make the liberty server pick this up dynamically during runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: Which class are you getting the NoClassDef on? Likely whatever was in that runtime jar is now replaced by a different implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have specific advice for that jar since I don't know what classes inside it are used by your application, but you can try scanning the application binary with the [Migration Toolkit for Application Binaries](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries) to see if it can make a recommendation for what you are trying to do. It will list all the incompatibilities it detects in the application and suggest ways to solve those issues.

It is likely that some application change will need to be made since that runtime jar is very tightly coupled to the WebSphere runtime itself and won't be compatible with Liberty.

The tool comes with a PDF explaining how to use it, make sure you read that to set the right parameters for the scan.

You might not have a say in this, but I'd personally recommend using a much newer version of Liberty as that version is about 5 years old. The current version is 20.0.0.1.